# Simple Python "if", "elif", "else"

Tags: python, if-statement

Making a "Mad Libs" style thing in Python for class, it's my first day, I've already picked up most of what I needed to know, but I'm not sure how to go about using the "if", "elif", "else" things. Here's what I have so far, basically, when the age is input I want it to choose if the person is an adult or a kid.

```
print "welcome to your short story"

name = raw_input("Input your name: ")
age = raw_input("Input your age: ")

if age > 21:
    age = "adult"
elif age < 21:
    age = "kid"


print "My name is ",name,"and I am a " ,age,"year old ",age
```

Comment: There are a few thing here that will give you problems, but as it sounds like you're teaching yourself I'll let you figure them out on your own :-) Do you have a specific question, or something specific about that doesn't work?

Comment: `raw_input()` returns a *string*, not an integer.

Comment: Use the int() function

Comment: what if  age = 21, then what?

Comment: You change the value of the variable "age" and in your final print statement, you print it twice. I assume you want both the actual age and either "adult" or "kid" printing in which case you'll need a second variable to assign one of these two to.

Comment: I realized I needed a different variable, and have changed that.

Comment: Okay, i've made the changes that @kolonel suggested, but if I print using the age of 13 it still prints "adult" instead of "kid".

Comment: @DuaneWalters make sure you compare integers, it is better because string comparison is done via dictionary ordering, so "21" < "5" is true, therefore covert input to integer and then do the comparison.

Comment: @kolonel, it is done on an index basis and len break a tie

Comment: @PadraicCunningham thanks for the comment, but I think what you described is dictionary ordering. Why do you think it is different?

Comment: @kolonel  because likes lists the comparison is done on the subelements at  matching indexes of each string, if all are equal but one is longer than the longer string wins .

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yes but that is the definition of dictionary ordering http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order

Comment: @DuaneWalters don't forget to give credit to whichever answer you found most helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You are overriding the inputted age with strings adult of kid.
2) You have to handle the case when age equals 21.
3) The age input needs to be converted to an integer.

Let's rewrite your code, and see how we can improve:

```
print "welcome to your short story"

name = raw_input("Input your name: ")
# Convert the input to an integer.
age = int(raw_input("Input your age: "))

# This is the status variable being either adult or child
# before you were overriding age variable with adult or kid
status = ""

# Also, you have to handle the case where the age equals 21, before 
# you were just checking if it is less or greater than 21
if age >= 21:
    status = "adult"
elif age < 21:
    status = "kid"

print "My name is ", name ," and I am a " , age ," year old " , status
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by foxygen, the int function is needed to convert your input from a string to an int

```
age = int(raw_input("Input your age: "))
```

There is a difference between the characters "1", "2", "3" and so forth, and the numbers 1, 2, 3, and so forth. Some languages try to convert for you, but python will not do this, so you end up comparing "32" to 21, which is an apples-to-oranges comparison.

Also, while you're safe in this particular instance, you'll notice how you're reassigning age while you're still computing based on its original value. This is not generally safe, and you would be better off assigning to a new variable:

```
if age > 21:
    age_label = "adult"
elif age < 21:
    age_label = "kid"
else:
    age_label = "person" # in case a 21 year old uses your program
```

You're safe in this case because the if/else construction will only ever execute one branch, but it's best not to get in the habit of rewriting the input value while you're still consulting it.

Answer (score 0):

I realized I needed a different value and have changed it.

```
print "welcome to your short story"

name = raw_input("What is your name?: ")
age = raw_input("How old are you?: ")
sex = raw_input("Are you a boy or a girl?: ")

if age > 21:
    targetAge = "adult"
elif age < 21:
    targetAge = "kid"


print "My name is ",name,"and I am a " ,age,"year old ",targetAge,"."
```

So, basically, when it is printed, it should read as "My name is _____ and I am a __ year kid/adult." Depending on the number they've input. The reason I'm not using the int() function is because that was never mentioned, this is literally the first day of class, so I'm going by what the instructor has gone over.

Comment: you are still comparing integers to strings. You are not handling the case where age could be 21. You fixed one problem. I suggest you read the answers given to you because they do have recommendations on how to improve.

Comment: `if age >= 21` to get equal to 21 also

Comment: If the int() function is not allowed then you must find a different way. I'm afraid your teacher just wants to impose busy work like that, though, because without using SOME more advanced features of python it could get unwieldy.  A separate case for  "age == '1'", "age == '2'", and so on, or the use of a list where you say "if age in ['1','2','3'...].  But any programming teacher I have ever had would expect you to use some initiative and look up the use of int() yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
print "Welcone to your Story"
name = raw_input("Please enter yout name: ")
    age = int(raw_input("please enter your age: "))
    if age >= 21:
        status = "an adult"
    else:
        #enter code here
        status = "a kid"
    print "My name is %r , I am  %r and I am %r years old" %(name,status,age)
```